# Audio Mixer Circuit - DIY

Tags: amplifier, audio

I want to build a simple audio mixer circuit with help of TL072 IC's.

The following is what I want:

Mix two/three(optional) stereo signals into one, and then live out into 3 outputs (1 for amplifier, 2 for plugged-in headphones, 3 for live recording in phone using microphone in).

There are already tutorials to make 3-channel input on internet but they are all single output and, I want 3 outputs.

Also the input of one of my channel output is very low.

[image]

Would be great if you can provide me a circuit diagram.

Comment: So, combine the circuits you found (and hint: It helps understanding them!) which give you 1 output with a circuit that makes 3 outputs out of 1 input. I guess you already thought of that – where are you stuck?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. "would be great if u can provide me circuit diagram" I expect it would but we don't work that way here. We will answer a specific question rather than a broad request. Click on the ? On the top-right of the screen and follow the tour to see what we expect.

Comment: by the way, the TL072 is indeed a popular opamp for audio applications, but I'm not sure you'd want to use it for all the jobs you have here. What was the technical reason you chose it? a) it's relatively expensive for what it does, b) it's not going to be strong enough to drive headphones at a reasonable volume / quality (a it does < 10 mA even at high supply voltages) c) it is only a two opamp in a package, and you'll need more than two opamps, because you'll want one to drive each your outputs (at least OUT1 and OUT2), and haven't done the summing at that point(and IN2 wants its own buffer)

Comment: "the input of one of my channel output is very low" The conventional approach in audio mixers is to use a pre-amplifier for small signals so that all the signals to be mixed are brought up to the same level (known as line level). Your mic pre-amp will need to be low noise. A 5532 op-amp is a common choice. Note there are plenty of small mixers commercially available to meet your requirement if you're not wishing to specifically construct your own circuit (though we won't recommend one).

Comment: So would quad channel ic like LM324 would be fine? And i choose  to create rather than buying existing ones cause I know its hard but its not impossible to make..maybe with a little guidance